# Probability expected value football problem

Tags: probability

> 5. The number of injuries at a college football game has the following probability distribution:
>
>    $$\begin{array}{|l:l|} \hline
>    \textrm{Number of injuries} & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hdashline
>    \textrm{Probability} & 0.14 & 0.33 & 0.23 & 0.17 & 0.09 & 0.04
>    \\ \hline
>    \end{array}$$
>
>    The coach must file a report whenever there is more than one injury in any game.
>
>    a. Calculate the expected number of reports filed in the next 20 games.
>
>    b. Calculate the standard deviation of the number of reports filed in the next 20 games.
>
>    c. Calculate the expected number of football games to be played before the first game in which there are at least four injuries.

Comment: Note: This does not involve Poisson distribution at all.

Comment: Rather than just cut-and-posting the problem, it is best practice to provide an indication of what you can do and where you are having difficulties.  What have you attempted so far?  People are more willing to help out if they can see that you have tried to do your own work.

Comment: I am trying to figure out what strategy I should use. Is this a binomial or poissson distribution?

Comment: Neither:-) To start can you count expected value of injuries in one game?

Comment: .14(0)+.33(1)+.23(2)+.17(3)+.09(4)+.04(5)=1.86

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:**

1. The probability that coach must fill the report after a game is the probability that there is more than one injury, count it and denote it $p$. Since obviously the numbers of injuries in different games are independent, number of filled report in 20 games has Binomial distribution with parameters $20$ and $p$ (sorry I made mistake in comments, did read your question too fast).
2. You already should know the distribution of number of reports.
3. If we say that $4$ and more injuries is failure, then number of games before  the first failure has [negative binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution).

---

Denote $X$ the number of injured players in one game, then 
$$P[X>1]=P[X=2] + P[X=3] + P[X=4] + P[X=5] = 0.53$$

---

The probability of at least four injured players in one game is 
$$P[X\geq 4]= P[X=4] + P[X=5] = 0.13,$$
number of games played before the first one with at least four injured has $NB(1,0.87)$ distribution. Its expected value is $\frac{0.87}{0.13}$.

Comment: Can you break this down a bit more, I still do not get you

Comment: What do you don't get. Can you count $p$?

Comment: .23(2)+.17(3)+.09(4)+.04(5) = 1.53?

Comment: $p$ is probability, so it cannot exceed 1! I included the correct computation in my answer. Also please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)  for writing equations.

Comment: ok so then the standard deviation would be: (2-1.53)^2 * .23 + (3-1.53)^2 * .17 + (4-1.53)^2 * .09 + (5-1.53)^2 * .04 = 1.204? the answer to b? and the answer to a would be 10.6?

Comment: Your answer to a is correct, to b not. What is the variance of binomial distribution with parameters $20,p$?  And once again please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: $$sqrt(20*.53(1-.53))=2.232$$?

Comment: How would I approach solving c?

Comment: Please read the article on the wiki. I have already told you the distribution of number of games to be played before the game with four injuries. So you just have to count the probability that there are at least four injuries at one game and then use the correct formula.

Comment: It seems like I am missing a variable. I get $$x-1Choose3 *.09^4(1-.09)^(x-4)$$ is this correct?

Comment: Your equation does not make sense at all! I edited my answer (in fact solved  your HW),  but I would strongly suggest that you go again through basics of probability cause I have a feeling that you do not get basic ideas;-)

Comment: Which equation did you use? Is my answer to b correct?

Comment: Note that the answer to c) is $\frac{1}{0.13}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas That would be the case if you count also the game with 4 injuries.  Since the question is number of games played **before** the one with four or more injuries, I really think my answer is correct since the mean is $\frac{1-p}{p}$

Comment: The term "before" is ambiguous. In elementary courses it often includes the trial in which the "success" occurs.  In a homework problem, OP would be safest in saying that if number of games before includes the game with $4$ or more, then the expected number is $1/(0.13)$, and if it does not it is one less.

Comment: @AndréNicolas My course taught me, that first fail doesn't count:-) However you are  right, you could see it that way, so it is up to OP to pick one answer.